# how can i show two histogram in same window but different plots in R?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I want to show the effect of removing outliers on my histogram, so I have to plot both hists together.

```
boxplot(Costs, Costs1,
    xlab=" Costs    and    Costs after  removig outliers",
    col=topo.colors(2))
```

so i tried this:

```
hist(Costs,Costs1,main="Histogram of  Maintenance_cost ",col="blue",
 border="darkblue",xlab="Total_cost",ylab=" ",yaxt = 'n',
 #ylim=c(0,3000),
 #xlim=c(0,max(My_Costs)),
 breaks=60)
```

the first code give me to box plot, but I tried it for hist it doesn't work
can anyone tell me how to do it in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a base R solution,  use `par` with `mfrow`.

```
set.seed(1234)
Costs = rnorm(5000, 100, 20)
OUT = which(Costs %in% boxplot(Costs, plot=FALSE)$out)
Costs1 = Costs[-OUT]

par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(5,1,2,1))
hist(Costs,main="Histogram of  Maintenance_cost ",col="blue",
 border="darkblue",xlab="Total_cost",ylab=" ",yaxt = 'n',
 breaks=60, xlim=c(30,170))
hist(Costs1,main="Maintenance_cost without outliers",col="blue",
 border="darkblue",xlab="Total_cost",ylab=" ",yaxt = 'n',
 breaks=60, xlim=c(30,170))
```

[image: Histograms with and without outliers]

Answer (score 2):

For multiple plots, you should use `ggplot2` with `facet_wrap`. Here is an example:

[Plot several histograms with ggplot in one window with several variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802151/plot-several-histograms-with-ggplot-in-one-window-with-several-variables)

Comment: i saw this library previously but couldnt understand how it exactly work cause in this samples two data stick together and then showed .i hoped to find something simpler or understand how it works with single histograms

Comment: @ssssoooo, if you use ggplot2, you indeed need to stack two tables together with data frame. Your tabe will be:

     value | label
     xx | Costs
     xx | Costs
     ...
     xx | Costs1
     xx | Costs1
    ....

Then you `facet_wrap(~label)`, ggplot two will know that you want to use label as the facet condition.